# Where are the locations of the Golden Beasts?

Tags: zelda-oracle-of-seasons

In *Oracle of Seasons*, you can find a cave that has a gold-robed old man. He mentions that, across the land, there exist 4 "Golden Beasts" that I can defeat to show my strength to him. Presumably to get something nice.

Along this, Dr. Left informs me that there are rumors of Golden Beasts that only show up in certain places in certain seasons. So there's a clue.

Problem is, Holodrum is a pretty big world. It's doable to search the entire world in every season (at least, the sections to which I can change season, so they can't be in the Natzu area or in the desert, nevermind not in the towns), but that could take some time. I can guess that the golden beasts will have a yellow hue but I am unsure if there are any other identifying factors for them.

Where are these elusive Golden Beasts located, and in which seasons? And, for bonus, how early can I complete this quest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- One is right in front of Level 2 in the Fall.
- One is in the screen below the Subrosia-Spool Swamp portal in the Summer
- One is on the ledge of the Tarm Ruins in Winter.
- One is to the right of Hero's Cave during Spring.

[Here](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Oracle_of_Seasons/Golden_Monsters) is a more in depth guide if you need it.